# What data type for internalformat specified as GL_RGBA?

Tags: opengl

In the OpenGL wiki [glTexImage2D](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glTexImage2D), it writes:

> internalFormat Specifies the number of color components in the
>   texture. Must be one of base internal formats given in Table 1, one of
>   the sized internal formats given in Table 2, or one of the compressed
>   internal formats given in Table 3, below.

In [OpenGL Programming Guide, Chapter 9, Texture Mapping](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html)

> By definition, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_RGB, and GL_RGBA
>   are lenient, because they do not ask for a specific resolution.

So if we assign GL_RGBA to the internalformat, what datatype is used?
Default by the GPU processor?

Comment: There is no default type, that's why constants like `GL_RGBA8` were created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size used for `GL_RGBA` is specifically undefined.

From the [OpenGL 4.5 spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf), section "8.5 Texture Image Specification", page 153 (emphasis added):

> The internal component resolution is the number of bits allocated to each value in a texture image. If internalformat is speciﬁed as a base internal format, the GL stores the resulting texture with internal component resolutions **of its own choosing**.

where "base internal format" refers to the formats listed in table 8.11, which includes `GL_RGBA`.

I would expect the chosen format to typically be `GL_RGBA8`, but there's really no guarantee. If you care about the size, you should use a sized format. In fact, I think you always should. The unsized formats seem to still be there to maintain backwards compatibility. I was always surprised that they were not removed in the Core Profile. For example the newer `glTexStorage*()` entry points, which serve as better replacements for `glTexImage*()` in many use cases, only accept sized internal formats.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question here is but GL_RGBA is normally a 4x8bit (4-byte/GL_BYTE type) format in the R,G,B,A order respectively but the constant is just saying that the buffer is composed of this order and not exactly how big each channel width is.

More info [here](http://www.solidgraphics.com/ClassGL/OnlineDocs/CRasterImage/GetStorageType.htm)

Edit: For some methods, you also need to specify this channel width (e.g. glReadPixels() or glDrawPixels())

Comment: But since the choice "GL_RGBA" exists, that means OpenGL can compile it. If it can compile it, that means some internalformat (including the components and data types) must be specified. So I guess some default values are assigned.